# Increase the speed of the bevel tool mouse-drag

Tags: 3d-view, bevel

After activating the bevel tool on edges, the "Amount Type: Offset" scales the bevel amount at the speed I would expect when I move my mouse.

Offset is rarely the type of bevel I want to use. Amount Type: Percent much more closely reflects the behavior of bevel tools in other software. When I change the tool to this mode, I have to drag the mouse across the viewport 10-20 times in order to move the amount value.

How can I change the speed that this works at? I do not want to have to adjust the bevel using the tool panel window every time, it's incredibly inefficient for a tool that gets used so much.

Comment: Are you tried apply scale?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into user preferences under input and change the settings used.

- Searching for bevel will quickly find what you want.
- Change the amount type to Percent.
- You could also change the amount setting so that it starts at say 5
- Save user settings so that it remains the default option when you restart blender.

[image: change default bevel options]

After using the bevel tool, you can adjust the settings that were used, these settings are available at the bottom of the toolbar region or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

If you look at the header of the 3D Viewport while using the bevel tool (and other tools), you will see a list of available options that can be used while interactively using the tool.

For the [bevel tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html), press <kbd>M</kbd> to change the mode, use the <kbd>[image: MW] mouse wheel</kbd> to change the number of segments. You can also type in the amount you want, so if you have mode set to percent you can type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to get a 25% bevel, you can also use backspace before accepting the bevel to adjust the setting you type in.